# Predicting the order/ranking of continuous observations

Tags: regression, classification, ranking, kendall-tau

I have a problem that is kind of similar to ordinal regression, but not the same. If I understand it correctly, in ordinal regression we try to predict ordered labels, e.g. the number of stars a book will get on Amazon by a certain customer. I.e., in ordinal regression the number of labels is fixed, say integers from 1 to 5 as with the stars on Amazon.
However, in my problem the number of labels is not fixed. I have an idea on how to start, but it's not complete and it also feels like I am reinventing the wheel.

Imagine you have a (training) dataset with the speed that, say, $N$ horses have achieved when running 100 meters together with some characteristics of the horse like age and weight. (I go with speed instead of time, because I want higher to be better.) The table looks something like that:

| horse_id | age | weight | speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2.5 | 250 | 20.15 |
| B | 1.5 | 230 | 22.34 |

There is only one row for each horse ID and the speed is measured so precisely that there are no ties, i.e., no two horses have achieved exactly the same speed. We can assume the same also about the features (age and weight). I have the recorded performance of those $N$ horses to train on. The task is, when given the features (age and weight) of another (i.e. new) set of $k$ horses, to be able to predict which one of those $k$ horses will be the fastest, which will be second and so on, i.e. to predict their ranking. (The number $k$ is not known yet.)
The naive approach would be to train a regression model on the speed, predict the speed of the new $k$ horses and then sort. However, this method optimizes things like root mean square, instead of the Kendall tau, which is what I actually care about.

**Idea**: Build pairs of observations. With $N$ horses in the training data I can build $N(N-1)/2$ different pairs and then get a binary target variable on whether the first horse in the pair was faster or not. For $N=3$ my training data will be

| id_horse_1 | id_horse_2 | age_difference | weight_difference | horse_1_faster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1.0 | 20 | 0 |
| A | C | 0.7 | -15 | 1 |
| B | C | -0.5 | 42 | 0 |

Then I can train a standard binary classification algorithm that takes the features *age_difference* and *weight_difference* and predicts *horse_1_faster*. For the new $k$ horses I can build the corresponding $k(k-1)/2$ pairs and predict the binary outcome. Then I can count the "wins" of each horse in those imaginary $k(k-1)/2$ 1-on-1 races and the horse with the most wins will be ranked first, the one with the second most wins - second, and so on. If there are two horses with the same number of wins, then the horse which won the race in that particular pair will be ranked higher.

But what should I do if there are three or more horses with the same number of wins? (e.g. horse $A$, $B$ and $C$ have each, say, 10 wins, but horse $A$ has won against horse $B$, horse $B$ has won against horse $C$, and horse $C$ has won against horse $A$)

Is there already an established way to solve such problems where one cares only about the Kendall ranking correlation coefficient? Perhaps something that is implemented in sklearn?

Answer (score 3):

Don’t think of creating pairs in the data.  Use an ordinal regression model for continuous Y, which requires no binning nor knowing how to transform Y.  The proportional odds model provides the Wilcoxon test and the probability of concordance (as used in $\tau$) from all possible pairs, as special cases.  Resources are [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo).

Comment: Wow, I didn't even dream to get an answer from Frank Harrell! The book about modelling strategies for regression is on my to-read list and, based on what I read in the article linked in the answer, I better start with Chapter 15.\
I will try a PO model. What concerns me, however, is that I have continuous covariates and I do not know in what functional form they enter into the equation, i.e. the conditional exceedance probability is modeled via the _expit_ function in the PO model and how the argument of the _expit_ function depends on each of the covariates is my input.

Comment: From the article it seems that, in general, one can still get good/useful results even if the PO assumption is violated, "unless the violation is in the form of a major reversal in the direction of the treatment effect." If I understand that correctly, the PO assumption not being fulfilled is particularly bad if the conditional exceedance probability is not a monotonic function of the covariate(s). However, this is what I am suspecting in my specific use case. The example with the racing horses was just to lay out the problem, but even there one can see such an effect being plausible.

Comment: The dependence on the weight of the horse should be non-monotonic. At small weights, increasing the weight means "making" the horse stronger which should increase the probability that the horse achieves a certain speed threshold. At high weights, increasing the weight means "making" the horse "fatter" which decreases the exceedance probability. In a more realistic example, similar effect should be observed when modelling a person's wage as a function of age. This is why I was trying to transform the problem in such a way as to apply a non-parametric approach like SVM or XGBoost.

Comment: To the extent that nonlinear relationships arise from nonlinear effects of predictors (covariates) it is very easy to solve for the smooth predictor transformations while fitting an ordinal model, using splines, as I did in the case study linked above.